# Issue with softlink

Tags: unix

I deleted symbolic link which was pointing to x binary, recreated a same link pointing to y binary i.e. now it’s pointing to y binary instead of x binary.

When I am running binary from its location it’s giving correct result. Let say the binary is at location

$/tmp/value>./y
Output is correct

If  I go to another directory,
/abd/def>/tmp/value/y
Its giving me output of x binary

Can anyone tell me why I am getting some issue.

Comment: What are these binaries?  Is it a program that looks at the name it's called as, to determine its functionality?

Comment: Hint: Use `ls -l yourlink` to see where it points (it may be a relative directory, which means it will (should) point to a file with respect to its location).  Also, if you move a relative symlink to another directory, its target changes.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `value` dir inside `tmp` dir is itself a symlink that changed inbetween? We're guessing here.

```
ls -la /tmp
ls -la /tmp/value
ls -la /abc/def
```

Comment: FYI bash's behavior when dealing with current directory through a symlink is very non-intuitive when certain things happen.

Answer (score 0):

Psychic debugging suggests you moved the directory that was current directory for your shell (or one of its parents) and are therefore now very confused.